# How to Insert Chinese character in SQL using C# Fluent

Tags: c#, sql-server, migration, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to use fluent C# to insert a chinese character in sql column (Nvarchar(4000)) 
Insert.Intotable("Story").Row(new { Name="中文", code="zh"
});
Note: By using directly SQl insert it work
However my requiremt is a bulk insert in C# and it is inserting  "???????"
Help please

Comment: And the reason why you are not allowed to use `bcp.exe` is...

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: `code`

 [Migration(201901011004)]
    public class InsertChineseStory : Migration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
          //  Delete.FromTable("Languages").Row(new { Code = "zh" });

            Insert.IntoTable("Languages").Row(new {
                Id=Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "中国郎",
                Code ="zh",
                Description = "N''中国郎'",
              LastUpdate=DateTime.Now,
              IsActive=1
            });

            
            }`code`